# How can I include external php file inside laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to include PHP function inside foreach loop, usually Im using @include to include blade files but I don't know why this time it doesn't work! but if I put the function inside the main file it works but when include it, doesn't work and i get the error Undefined variable: total_price (View: ....

I want to use this function in multiple files that's why I need to include it

this is the content of the file I want to include: cart_functions.blade.php

```
@php
 $total_extra_price = $cart->extras->sum('price');
 $food_price = $cart->variations->sum('price');
 $total_extra_variation_price = $cart->extra_variations->sum('price');
 $total_price = $total_extra_price + $food_price + $total_extra_variation_price;
@endphp
```

main.blade.view

```
 @foreach($carts as $cart)
    @include('cart.cart_functions')
   {{number_format($total_price, 2, '.', ',')}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is the folder address of the blade file? 
Sample include and transfer information => 
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as the parent template does not know anything about the scope of the included template

Comment: @AkbarRahmanii the folder address is view->cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel Blade, variable scope is parent to child and not the other way around.

When you are including a Blade View, the rendering only makes the variables available inside the scope of the specific rendering.

You need to either output the `$total_price` in your included view or make the calculations in the parent (eg. the controller) and pass them to the relevant view.